# Webpack not matching with API schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have this simple hello world application, however I get this error:

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
>
> -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.

My webpack file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * @param {string} command process to run
 * @param {string[]} args command line arguments
 * @returns {Promise<void>} promise
 */
const runCommand = (command, args) => {
    const cp = require("child_process");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const executedCommand = cp.spawn(command, args, {
            stdio: "inherit",
            shell: true
        });

        executedCommand.on("error", error => {
            reject(error);
        });

        executedCommand.on("exit", code => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
};

/**
 * @param {string} packageName name of the package
 * @returns {boolean} is the package installed?
 */
const isInstalled = packageName => {
    if (process.versions.pnp) {
        return true;
    }

    const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("graceful-fs");

    let dir = __dirname;

    do {
        try {
            if (
                fs.statSync(path.join(dir, "node_modules", packageName)).isDirectory()
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (_error) {
            // Nothing
        }
    } while (dir !== (dir = path.dirname(dir)));

    // https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v18.9.1/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1274
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-warning-comments
    // @ts-ignore
    for (const internalPath of require("module").globalPaths) {
        try {
            if (fs.statSync(path.join(internalPath, packageName)).isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (_error) {
            // Nothing
        }
    }

    return false;
};

/**
 * @param {CliOption} cli options
 * @returns {void}
 */
const runCli = cli => {
    const path = require("path");
    const pkgPath = require.resolve(`${cli.package}/package.json`);
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
    const pkg = require(pkgPath);

    if (pkg.type === "module" || /\.mjs/i.test(pkg.bin[cli.binName])) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
        import(path.resolve(path.dirname(pkgPath), pkg.bin[cli.binName])).catch(
            error => {
                console.error(error);
                process.exitCode = 1;
            }
        );
    } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
        require(path.resolve(path.dirname(pkgPath), pkg.bin[cli.binName]));
    }
};

/**
 * @typedef {Object} CliOption
 * @property {string} name display name
 * @property {string} package npm package name
 * @property {string} binName name of the executable file
 * @property {boolean} installed currently installed?
 * @property {string} url homepage
 */

/** @type {CliOption} */
const cli = {
    name: "webpack-cli",
    package: "webpack-cli",
    binName: "webpack-cli",
    installed: isInstalled("webpack-cli"),
    url: "https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli"
};

if (!cli.installed) {
    const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("graceful-fs");
    const readLine = require("readline");

    const notify =
        "CLI for webpack must be installed.\n" + `  ${cli.name} (${cli.url})\n`;

    console.error(notify);

    let packageManager;

    if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "yarn.lock"))) {
        packageManager = "yarn";
    } else if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "pnpm-lock.yaml"))) {
        packageManager = "pnpm";
    } else {
        packageManager = "npm";
    }

    const installOptions = [packageManager === "yarn" ? "add" : "install", "-D"];

    console.error(
        `We will use "${packageManager}" to install the CLI via "${packageManager} ${installOptions.join(
            " "
        )} ${cli.package}".`
    );

    const question = `Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): `;

    const questionInterface = readLine.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stderr
    });

    // In certain scenarios (e.g. when STDIN is not in terminal mode), the callback function will not be
    // executed. Setting the exit code here to ensure the script exits correctly in those cases. The callback
    // function is responsible for clearing the exit code if the user wishes to install webpack-cli.
    process.exitCode = 1;
    questionInterface.question(question, answer => {
        questionInterface.close();

        const normalizedAnswer = answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("y");

        if (!normalizedAnswer) {
            console.error(
                "You need to install 'webpack-cli' to use webpack via CLI.\n" +
                    "You can also install the CLI manually."
            );

            return;
        }
        process.exitCode = 0;

        console.log(
            `Installing '${
                cli.package
            }' (running '${packageManager} ${installOptions.join(" ")} ${
                cli.package
            }')...`
        );

        runCommand(packageManager, installOptions.concat(cli.package))
            .then(() => {
                runCli(cli);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                process.exitCode = 1;
            });
    });
} else {
    runCli(cli);
}
```

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config file is:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js'

   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8001
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins:[
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './index.html'
      })
   ]
}
```

I expected to below output after running **npm start** in CLI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no "query" property. Use the options property.

```
 options: {
 presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
 }
```